# Edit opening and closing hours of week (daywise)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm working on opening and closing hours of week (Daywise). I found jquery.businessHours plugin it's working perfectly i can successfully insert data which in json format. I have inserted data in json format like this. But opening and closing hours of weeks are businesswise so there is a functionality that business owner can edit their business hours.

Please visit this js fiddle Link : 
https://jsfiddle.net/wdpu6jbf/

I tried with this code,

```
$adminid = '135';
$res = $conn->query("select json_data_timing_hours from timing_hours where admin_id='$adminid'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['json_data_timing_hours'];
```

So i got following Json Data which are stored in database:

**Array1**

```
[
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "timeFrom": "09:00",
    "timeTill": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "timeFrom": "09:00",
    "timeTill": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "timeFrom": "09:00",
    "timeTill": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "timeFrom": "09:00",
    "timeTill": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "timeFrom": "09:00",
    "timeTill": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "timeFrom": null,
    "timeTill": null
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "timeFrom": null,
    "timeTill": null
  }
]
```

Now, my problem is how can i edit field in rectangle with colour and numbers also. is it possible when i come on this page with edit request it's filled according to the colour and data which are stored in database because everything is comes from script which are very tough to understand.

Ex : in Array1  five days a week and time is from 09:00 to 18:00. if data is stored in Array2's manner.

**Array2**

```
[
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "timeFrom": "09:00",
    "timeTill": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "timeFrom": "09:00",
    "timeTill": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "timeFrom": null,
    "timeTill": null
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "timeFrom": null,
    "timeTill": null
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "timeFrom": null,
    "timeTill": null
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "timeFrom": null,
    "timeTill": null
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "timeFrom": null,
    "timeTill": null
  }
]
```

Then while edit request monday and tuesday's colour is light green and other colours are red with specific time. 
If whole code is not possible from yours side then please give me a hint to work. If any other information is needed please tell me.

Business hour js link (which we need to change according to the result) : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.businessHours/1.0.1/jquery.businessHours.js

Open this link I have to change operationTime, defaultOperationTimeFrom & defaultOperationTimeTill variables dynamically but how i can't figured it out.

**EDIT:** 
I have to change this specific part of above js,

```
  operationTime: [
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {isActive: false},
                {isActive: false}
            ],
            defaultOperationTimeFrom: '9:00',
            defaultOperationTimeTill: '18:00',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add onblur event for time textbox, Means if any person edit the time and move the cursor , using onblur event you can Edit the field in the database, and you should use some unique ID or class in the textbox.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: yeah brother. i tried with it also but the problem is that all the data are coming from that plugin's javascript so i can't figured out how i can compare with colours and fields which are selected in this dropdown?